# How to get other system's time using network programming in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

I want to get another system's time which is a server where both systems are connected through LAN. Give me some ideas?

Comment: What options have you considered?

Comment: can  I use other system time is there any possibilities

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [An SNTP Client in C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_date_time/timeroutines/article.php/c4207/)

Or, for the REALLY simple solution, shell out to `NET TIME`

```
net time \\computer
```

And capture the stdout.

Comment: I like the `net time` solution: no extra dependencies.

Comment: Is there any possibilities of using other system
 time

Answer (score 0):

If the server is a windows operating system, you could try to get the time remotely using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394590(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A more recent project [SNTP time class](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/27-networking/649-sntp-time-class.html)